# R Creating Duplicate Dates Given Value

Tags: r, tidyverse

Using R, I need to duplicate a set of dates. For example, if my dataset was:

Date      |   Count 
1/1/2020  |       5

What I want to be able to do is have the following in a single column:

Date 
1/1/2020 
1/1/2020 
1/1/2020 
1/1/2020 
1/1/2020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   uncount(Count) %>%
   as_tibble
# A tibble: 5 x 1
#  Date    
#  <fct>   
#1 1/1/2020
#2 1/1/2020
#3 1/1/2020
#4 1/1/2020
#5 1/1/2020
```

---

If the column 'Count' is not numeric, it would show the error message because `weights` should be numeric

```
df1 %>% 
    uncount(as.character(Count))
```

> Error: `weights` must evaluate to a numeric vector

The OP mentioned that there are `NA` elements.  In that case, use `replace_na` to replace the NA elements to 0 and then apply the `uncount`

```
df1 %>%
    uncount(replace_na(Count, 0))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Date = "1/1/2020", Count = 5)
```

Comment: When I attempt using uncount, I receive the following error `"Error: weights must evaluate to a numeric vector"`

Comment: @JosephWooster ii assume the 'Count' column to be `numeric` class and not character

Comment: that was my problem. The column was a character as it was holding a value of "NA". Replacing NA with 0s allowed me to run uncount. Thank you for the quick help!!

Comment: @JosephWooster If you could convert the 'Count' to `numeric`, it should work i.e. `df1 %>% mutate(Count = as.numeric(as.character(Count))) %>% uncount(Count))`